# creating Entry form in Umbraco for Add/Edit/Delete/Search functions

Tags: umbraco

This is repeatedly asked many times, however i couldn't find appropriate solution for my problem.

I want to create an Entry Form which will consists of following elements:

Text boxes, drop down fields (auto populated) , check boxes , radio buttons

After my research

i found that i need to create user control, or script file for above form and access it via Macro.

I don't want to use User control as my first preference is to controller-View-Model (i.e. cshtml)

I want to follow MVC approach to create above form. So

1) Do i need to create a seperate project for Add/Edit/Delete/Search Data Entry form?
2) OR i need to create cshtml file for the same(not so clear about this approach)

I'm looking this data entry form with easier for customization and i could use it in other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

From Umbraco 4.10 up to 6.0.x you can use MVC in Umbraco so there's no need to use an usercontrol. You probably want to use a [SurfaceController](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers) where you can add any Action you want. The rest is standard MVC (Razor views to build your textboxes, drop downs, ...).

Check out the [Umbraco MVC documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/mvc/) where they explain how to use MVC in an Umbraco project.

Comment: I've written a few posts on using MVC in Umbraco for front-end pages or back-end pages. http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/category/development/umbraco/